# send a transaction in blockchain

Tags: transactions

When a transaction is transmitted on the blockchain, where does it go exactly?
where is the transaction pool, where is it saved?
How do the miners know that a new transaction is launched on the blockchain network?
Cordially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a transaction is transmitted on the blockchain, where does it go exactly?

The pending transactions reside in the txpool of Ethereum, you can browse it here: https://etherscan.io/txsPending

Miners monitor the txpool for new transactions to validate, usually opting to validate transactions with the higher gas prices compared to lower gas prices.

Comment: the other node of ethereum have also  access  to the memool because it 's public ??

Comment: The transaction pool data is public information, yes.

Comment: @KhYa I adjusted my use of the word "mempool" to "txpool" or "transaction pool" as it seems like more appropriate terminology.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a transaction this means that you either created a contract or sending ether to some other EOA or interacting with a pre-existing contract.

The transaction you send should contain some important properties/features such as to what address, gas limit, etc these data are available [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/transactions/).

As a matter of fact, your wallet will sign this contract using cryptographic rules outlined on the Ethereum yellow paper. Then, only the RLP-encode of your transaction is transmitted to one of the nodes on the Ethereum blockchain. Accordingly the RLP-encoded transaction will be transmitted between different nodes (Ethereum clients) on the network. It will be stored on the mempool of each node, where it depends on the node administrator who will priortise your transaction depending on the gas you are willing to pay. Then, depending on the miner's luck in producing the nonce of the block, he will receive an ether if he was able to record your transaction on the Ethereum decentralized database.

The transaction you see in the pending transaction pool is accessible to all nodes but some nodes get these transactions before other nodes and hence they start working on finding the nonce of the block before other nodes. These nodes save these pending transactions on their localized mempool (memory pool)

I suggest you read the Mastering Ethereum book to get more guidance as your question does not have a straight forward answer.